# Remote Debugging C++ Application, Deployment failed on VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I am trying to remote debug C++ application. VS 2015 could able to connect to remote machine and on remote machine "VS 2015 Remote Debugger" is detecting valid user is connected to it. But deployment is failing with errors in visual studio

> 2>Error: Unable to deploy local file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\concrt140d.dll' (remote file path 'C:\remotetemp\concrt140d.dll')
>   2>Error: Unable to deploy local file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\msvcp140d.dll' (remote file path 'C:\remotetemp\msvcp140d.dll')
>   2>Error: Unable to deploy local file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vccorlib140d.dll' (remote file path 'C:\remotetemp\vccorlib140d.dll')
>   2>Error: Unable to deploy local file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vcruntime140d.dll' (remote file path 'C:\remotetemp\vcruntime140d.dll')
>   2>Error: Unable to deploy local file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCXXAMP\vcamp140d.dll' (remote file path 'C:\remotetemp\vcamp140d.dll')
>   2>Error: Unable to deploy local file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugMFC\mfc140ud.dll' (remote file path 'C:\remotetemp\mfc140ud.dll')
>   2>Error: Unable to deploy local file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugMFC\mfcm140ud.dll' (remote file path 'C:\remotetemp\mfcm140ud.dll')
>   2>Error: Unable to deploy local file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOpenMP\vcomp140d.dll' (remote file path 'C:\remotetemp\vcomp140d.dll')

I followed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx and set parameters as specified

Setting

> Remote Command =>  C:\remotetemp\myapp.exe
>
> Working Directory => C:\remotetemp
>
> Remote Server Name => remotemachine
>
> Connection => Remote with Windows Authentication
>
> Debugger Type => Auto
>   //I tried native also but didn't work for me
>
> Deployment Directory => C:\remotetemp

Any idea what might be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got resolved by:
It seems source machine (debugger) copies some files into the specified folder(c:\remotetemp) of the remote machine. Hence make sure that the directory has all the required access to create files.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is late, but i had this error and discovered its because my the remote system i was pushing files too was out of hard drive space.  So make sure the drive on the system your pushing too isnt full.